# Auto generate initials when application inserts value in to a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to auto generate initials from first, last and MI columns when application inserts value in to a SQL Server table. I was thinking about using computed columns but I am not sure if this is the best way to go in this situation. The script must look at the existing initials column and make the new value is unique in some way. Perhaps by affixing X at the end (XX when X was already used and XXX after that and so on) when the value already exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. ty

Comment: Perhaps you could share a little bit of information about what you are really trying to do? Tables and examples would be a huge step in the right direction. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: And when you have two John Smiths in your table, with no MIs?

Comment: And what exactly would you be doing with these unique values?

Comment: @Kev this is why I am looking to add the Xes at the end when we already have two John Smiths. First would be JS the 2nd JSX and if there was a 3rd his initials would be JSXX or something similar, maybe JSY or JSZ

Comment: Oh, literal X's, I see.  Well, the solution would depend on which method you want to use, JSXX or JSY.  With the latter, what do want to happen after JSZ?

Comment: @DanBracuk Use them to uniquely identify mail going out of our office :-)
I offered other methods of IDing but powers at be insist initials are used.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the default constraint to the existing `initial` column as `Default Left(FirstName,1) + Left(LastName,1)` to achieve this.

Comment: This works and I did get that far but this does not guarantee the value will be unique.

Comment: You should add one more constraint which is `Unique`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any details ,you have to figure out how do you want to do the partition and order by:....

```
 select all_colmuns , case when  max( (Left(FirstName,1) + Left   (LastName,1))    
  over(PARTITION BY all_columns 
   ORDER BY id_primary_key ROWS BETWEEN   UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) = 
          (Left(FirstName,1) + Left(LastName,1)) then 
       (Left(FirstName,1) + Left(LastName,1)) + 'X' 
    else (Left(FirstName,1) + Left(LastName,1)) end as intials 
   from your_table
```

Comment: This looks good but still will not deal with situations where I already have two names that are the same and adding a third (which unfortunately does happen). Could COUNT function be used to determine if the same same names are already in the system and based on the number returned add X or XX, etc.? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
  select b.*, case when rn > 1 then intials_1 + replicate ('X' , rn-1)
  else intials_1 end as intials_final
  from     
       (  select a.all_columns ,
    row_number () over (partition by intials_1 order by intials_1) as rn
   from
   (select all_columns ,Left(FirstName,1) + Left(LastName,1) as    intials_1     
    from     your_tbl )a )b
```

Comment: Idea is generating a base column with the initials as they are and then adding the X as many times as it was repeated....